# Make Entity bounce off another entity in ImpactJS

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I have a Player Entity that is governed by gravity and I have another entity at the bottom of the screen that moves around.

When my falling player entity hits the entity at the bottom I want it to bounce off of it.

Ideally I'd like to use the .bounciness property of the player entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your bottom entity to contain the following properties:

```
checkAgainst: ig.Entity.TYPE.A, // player entity type
collides: ig.Entity.COLLIDES.ACTIVE
```

Then you want your `check()` method of your bottomEntity to reverse the velocity of the player entity when it collides with it.

```
check: function(other) {
  other.vel.y -= 100; // you could also use other.accel.y
}
```

Also if you want you can handle deflection angles with collisions as well (similar to the Arkanoid games):

If the player hits in the center, you want it to go straight up. If it hits on the right half, you want it to go right; if it hits on the left, you want it to go left.

So find where the player hits the bottom entity, and find its angle relative to the end of the entity.

```
var playerPos = player.pos.x - bottomEntity.pos.x;
var relativePos = ( bottomEntity.size.x - playerPos);
var angle = relativePos * ( Math.PI / bottomEntity.size.x ); // translate to radians - this finds the number of radians per bottom entity pixel
```

Once you got the angle, take the `cos` of it to grab the direction. Multiply the direction times the bottom entities velocity, and you've got the bottom entities new velocity.

```
var newVel = Math.cos( angle ) * bottomEntity.vel.x;
```

Then your `check()` method would look like this:

```
check: function(other) {
  var playerPos = other.pos.x - bottomEntity.pos.x;
  var relativePos = ( bottomEntity.size.x - playerPos);
  var angle = relativePos * ( Math.PI / bottomEntity.size.x ); // translate to radians - this finds the number of radians per bottom entity pixel
  other.vel.y -= newVel;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I asked but I had a suspicion that the answer you provided would probably be the only way.  Marked as correct for that.  Upvoted because you solved the angle thing for me thank you.